# Play Framework not recognizing path parameter

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I am working on a web-app using the Play Framework. I am trying to pass a variable through a dynamic URI. I am following the example shown [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/routes#syntax). However, I am getting this error:

```
not enough arguments for method showClients: (clientId: Long)play.mvc.Result. Unspecified value parameter clientId.
```

routes file:

```
GET     /clients/{clientId}                   controllers.Application.showClients
```

Controller Code:

```
public static Result showClients(Long clientId) {
    Client c = clientFinder.byId(clientId);
    return ok(client.render(c));
}
```

URL

```
http://localhost:9000/clients/1
```

Does anyone see a problem with my code? After googling around, I have found similar questions, but no one with the exact same problem, so I am thinking it is something simple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoops...It looks like I was looking at documentation for a previous version of Play. The current documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaRouting) shows that my routes file should look like this:

```
GET   /clients/:clientId     controllers.Application.showClients(clientId : Long)
```

Thanks to anyone who looked into finding an answer to the question.